# Suppose $B$ is a set and $F$ is a family of sets. Prove that $\bigcup\{A \setminus B | A \in F\} \subseteq \bigcup(F \setminus P(B))$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-writing

This is Velleman's exercise 3.4.14 (P is used for power set):

Suppose $B$ is a set and $F$ is a family of sets. Prove that

$$\bigcup\{A \setminus B \mid A \in F\} \subseteq \bigcup(F \setminus P(B))$$

I am stuck on this one. I think my problem is that I don't fully understand how to translate $\bigcup\{A \setminus B \mid A \in F\}$. And I think the translation of $\bigcup(F \setminus P(B))$ would be $\exists A  \in F(x \in A \wedge x \notin P(B))$.

A proof in real Velleman expository style would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $x \in \bigcup\{A\setminus B \mid A\in F\}$. Then, by the definition of the union, there exists $A\in F$ such that $x \in A\setminus B$. Since $A$ contains an element that is not in $B$, we have $A\not\subseteq B$ and consequently $A\in F\setminus P(B)$. Therefore $x\in A \subseteq \cup(F\setminus P(B))$.

The main issue with this problem appears to be the notation and the definitions. Usually authors will use script or calligraphic letters for sets of sets, and reserve the capital letters for sets of elements. (Set theoretically these are the same, but it still helps.)
Using this style, let me replace $F$ by $\mathscr{F}$ and $P(B)$ by $\mathscr{P}(B)$.

The second issue is the question as to how $\cup (\mathscr{F}\setminus\mathscr{P}(B))$ is defined. Well $\mathscr{F}\setminus\mathscr{P}(B)$ is a family of sets, so we need to determine how $\cup\mathscr{E}$ is defined for a family of sets $\mathscr{E}$. It is simply
$$
\cup \mathscr{E} := \bigcup_{E\in\mathscr{E}}E = \{x \mid x\in E\ \text{for some}\ E\in\mathscr{E}\}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\bigcup \{A \setminus B \ | \ A \in F\}
&=& \{x \ | \ \exists A: (x \in A \setminus B) \land (A \in F)\} \\
&=& \{x \ | \ \exists A: (x \in A) \land (A \in F) \land (x \notin B)\} \\
\bigcup \left( F \setminus \mathcal P(B) \right)
&=& \{x \ | \ \exists A: (x \in A) \land (A \in F \setminus \mathcal P(B))\} \\
&=& \{x \ | \ \exists A: (x \in A) \land (A \in F) \land (A \notin \mathcal P(B))\} \\
\end{array}$$

As $(A \in \mathcal P(B)) \iff (A \subseteq B)$ and $(A \subseteq B) \implies (x \in B)$, we have $(x \notin B) \implies (A \notin \mathcal P(B))$, thus $\exists A: (x \in A) \land (A \in F) \land (x \notin B)$ implies $\exists A: (x \in A) \land (A \in F) \land (A \notin \mathcal P(B))$, thus the first set $\subseteq$ the second set.